# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\infty} k^{D-2} \sin(kr)/(k^2+m^2) dk$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

I'm trying to find this integral:

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} {k^{D-2} \sin(kr) \over (k^2+m^2)} dk$$

where $m$ and $r$ are real, and $D$ is a positive integer.

For odd $D$, I extended the integral to range over the real line, changed the integrand to an exponential, and used the residue theorem on the UHP to get:

$$I = {\pi\over 2}(im)^{D-3}e^{-mr}$$

Is this approach alright, and is there a way to evaluate this integral for even $D$?

Comment: yupp this approach works out nicely for odd $D$. for even $D$ there is no closed form in terms of elementary functions, u will have to refer to special functions, the so called sine/cosine integrals

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\geq 0$ be even.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{n}\sin (ax)}{x^2+b^2}\,\mathrm{d}x&=\int_0^\infty (-1)^{n/2}\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial a^n}\frac{\sin (ax)}{x^2+b^2}\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=(-1)^{n/2}\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial a^n} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (ax)}{x^2+b^2}\,\mathrm{d}x \\
\end{align*}

Therefore, if you had a closed form for the base even $D$ case, you could extend it like this.

Looking at this, I'm not sure there is anything nice for this integral, but I'm not really the best at these.